# Why does a change under the public folder triggers auto reload?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, sbt

I'm currently developing a web app using Play Framework 2.3.0 and AngularJS. I use the `/public` folder of Play Framework to serve my AngularJS app.

Every change I make during development triggers a full reload by Play, which is kind of annoying since I have a time expensive computation in the `Global.beforeStart` method.

Why does it trigger an auto reload since, as [the Play 2.3.0 documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Anatomy) says:

> Resources stored in the `public` directory are static assets that are
>   served directly by the Web server.

Any idea on how to disable the auto reload feature for the `public` folder ?

EDIT: Another thought: is there a way to serve ressources from an external folder that's not monitored using the `Assets` controller ?

Comment: It might be of some help (frmo [How are public assets packaged?](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets)): *"During the build process, the contents of the public folder are processed and added to the application classpath."* I read it that Play accesses assets from the classpath after processing the files and the public directory is monitored.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand the fact that Play needs the `/public` folder to be in the classpath. Although its not very understandable why it triggers auto reload since the ressources it contains are supposedly _static_. Is there a way to serve ressources from an external folder that's not monitored using the `Assets` controller ? I haven't found a way yet.

Comment: Known [issue](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2905) at the moment. Hopefully fixed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to my build.sbt:

```
    watchSources := (watchSources.value
      --- baseDirectory.value / "public"     ** "*").get
```

It will remove '/public' from the list of folders that are being watched. Beware that this might break stuff, but it is a nice workaround until the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Reloads are **not** triggered by *source* file changes, they are triggered by *classpath* changes.  Of course, a source file change may trigger a classpath change, but it also may not.

The way Play's run mode is it watches for all source file changes, this includes changes to the public directory and also assets, since there may need to be processing done on these.  Whenever there is a change, it asks sbt to recompile - this means recompile everything including static assets and scala/java files.

When sbt recompiles it uses incremental compilation - that means, it stores the result of the last compile, and looks at it to work out whether there is any new work that needs to be done since the last compile.  If there's not, then it skips the compile.

The same is done for copying resources from the resource directory to the classpath.

So, after Play has asked sbt to recompile, it then checks - were there any changes to the classpath?  If there were, it reloads.  But, if all you changed was a javascript file, then there shouldn't have been.

However, you're not the only person changing files - if you have configured SBT to generate some files for you, maybe a Java/Scala source file, or maybe just some resource in the conf directory, and the task you've written does this every time, whether it needs to do this or not - well this may be a classpath change.

So, to solve your problem, check any tasks that you've written, or any plugins you're using, to see if they are generating sources or resources.  If they are, and they aren't being smart about it, ie, they're regenerating the same files when they don't need to, then this is likely to cause Play to reload on any source file change, since it means every time sbt recompiles, the file is regenerated, which changes the classpath.

Comment: If I `touch` a .js file in the public directory of my subproject it triggers a full recompilation and restart.  I don't have anything enabled other than `enablePlugins(PlayScala)`, `routesGenerator` and `fork in run := true`.  Is there anything else that could be triggering it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are (or were) using the BuildInfoPlugin? (or maybe other people who find this question, use it)

Play Framework was always restarting for me, whenever I touched anything in `public/`. Eventually I noticed this was because I'm using the SBT BuildInfoPlugin, https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo, and had configured it to include build timestamps, and also `git status`, in the generated build info. After I removed those parts of the build info, Play no longer recompiles or reloads after changes in `public/`.

This was with SBT 0.13.15 and SBT 1.1.1, and Play Framework 2.6.9 and 2.6.12.

This is what I removed:
`buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.BuildTime`
and:
`BuildInfoKey.action("gitStatus") {  "git status".!!.trim })`.

<sub>(I didn't need to configure `watchSources` or `playMonitoredFiles` for Play to stop recopmiling & reloading.)</sub>